Laravel - create an installer for project
Hi I've created a install.php for my Laravel project to run migrations & db seeders in it.
  require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
    file_put_contents('.env', $envContent);


    ob_start();
    $kernel->call('migrate', ['--force' => true]);
    $kernel->call('db:seed');

This runs okay, saving the .env file and executes the artisan command.
But I'm getting an error after running the migrate
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = spnv_store and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
Here is the problem, my username isn't root and host is not localhost, I'm starting to think when I call migrate like this it's not taking the db information from .env file,
Can anybody help?

Have you tried running the file_put_contents before any of the requires?

i did @apokryfos
